# Embedding IronPython's stdlib in VS extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ironpython, vsix

I'm currently writing a Visual Studio extension, which provides scripting capabilities. I'm using IronPython (the newest one), but I have some problems with Python's standard libraries.

As I understand, all necessary files reside in the `<IronPython folder>\Lib` folder. I cannot rely on my users installing IronPython, so I have to provide these files in other way.

If it is possible, I'd simply embed the whole Lib folder in my assembly and allow IronPython access to it from the code, but I'm not sure, if this is possible. I can try to add the Lib folder to extension's package and extract it to wherever Visual Studio will copy my extension's files, but I'm unsure, how to get access to them during extension's runtime. Also, I'd like to set appropriate paths transparently to the user and I'm also unsure, whether this can be done.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume that there is a way to include them in the VSIX file and also know where they are on disk - at least, you could use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` for find the IronPython assembly and `Assembly.Location` to find where it is, and hope the VSIX puts the Lib directory near that. (My only experience with VSIX was a while ago and I hated it, so I can't provide much advice in that department.)

Assuming you're embedding IronPython, once you have the location you can just use `ScriptEngine.SetSearchPaths` to tell IronPython where the Lib directory is. If you're shelling out to ipy.exe then set the IRONPYTHONPATH environment variable before starting it.

Comment: There indeed is a way to include files in VSIX container and that's how I've solved this problem in the end. I've also experimented with compiling the scripts into an assembly, but that required the end user to call `clr.LoadAssembly("StdLib")` each time, so I dropped that idea. Thanks for help!

Comment: If you use `ScriptRuntime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.LoadFrom("path/to/StdLib.dll"))` you shouldn't need to do it for every script.